# See Batch File Below. Why does my batch file display Japanese/Chinese characters when it outputs to a text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

See Batch File Below. Why does my batch file display Japanese/Chinese characters when it outputs to a text file? I'm automating my setup process because I set up numerous PCs a week. When executing the following in command prompt, it returns the correct output but in my batch file it displays a bunch of Chinese characters.

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"
systeminfo | findstr c:/"installed Physical MEmory"
```

Here is the batch file in full and the output.

```
set OLDNAME=%computername%
set /p var1="Enter the PC Name that will be used when joined to the domain: "

wmic computersystem where caption="%OLDNAME%" rename %var1% 

>output.txt (
wmic csproduct get name
wmic bios get serialnumber
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"
wmic cpu get name
systeminfo | findstr c:/"installed Physical MEmory"

)
```

OUTPUT BELOW:

```
MYPC                        
Surface with Windows 8 Pro  
SerialNumber  (Witheld for obvious reasons)
协丠浡㩥†††††††††䴠捩潲潳瑦圠湩潤獷ㄠ‰牐൯ഊ上愀洀攀                                      ഀ਀䤀渀琀攀氀⠀刀⤀ 䌀漀爀攀⠀吀䴀⤀ 椀㔀ⴀ㌀㌀㄀㜀唀 䌀倀唀 䀀 ㄀⸀㜀　䜀䠀稀  ഀ਀吀瑯污倠票楳慣⁬敍潭祲›††ⰳ㠹‰䉍਍癁楡慬汢⁥桐獹捩污䴠浥牯㩹㈠㈬ㄳ䴠ൂ
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the output from the command `CHCP`?

Comment: When writing to a file, wmic.exe uses UTF-16. It's actually the only sane output from this silly program. When writing to the console or a pipe it hard codes using a lossy encoding to the OEM codepage, even if the console isn't using the OEM codepage.

Comment: In case it's not obvious from the above, you're seeing CJK characters from the non-Unicode `systeminfo` output intermixed with the wmic output. wmic starts the output.txt file with a UTF-16 BOM, so most programs will rightly try to handle the `systeminfo` output as UTF-16 encoded text, which shows up as CJK characters.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a programmer by any means so I don't fully grasp the issue. Any suggestions for resolving the issue? I appreciate it!

Comment: You can't combine the output of a command that outputs UTF-16 with a command that outputs text encoded with a legacy codepage. But note how I said wmic.exe will output text encoded with the OEM codepage when writing to a pipe. That means you can use a `for /f` loop if you don't care about a lossy encoding, which shouldn't be a problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can save as your output.txt as unicode-8 then reuse your script